# Problems with luaotfload and MacTeX 2015

Tags: mactex, luaotfload

I'm trying to come to terms with LuaLaTeX (MacTeX 2015, Mac OS 10.10.4). I am trying to run `luaotfload -vvv -u` but it hangs:

```
17:11 ~% luaotfload-tool -vvv -u
luaotfload | util : Setting the log level to 3.
luaotfload | util : Task completed successfully.
luaotfload | db : Updating the font names database.
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.
luaotfload | db : Updating the font names database.
luaotfload | db : Blacklisted file "Skia.ttf" via "/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-blacklist.cnf".
luaotfload | db : Blacklisted file "LastResort.ttf" via "/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-blacklist.cnf".
luaotfload | db : Blacklisted file "lingoes.ttf" via "/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-blacklist.cnf".
luaotfload | db : Blacklisted file "Diablindall.ttf" via "/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-blacklist.cnf".
luaotfload | db : Blacklisted file "spltfgbd.ttf" via "/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-blacklist.cnf".
luaotfload | db : Blacklisted file "spltfgbi.ttf" via "/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-blacklist.cnf".
luaotfload | db : Blacklisted file "spltfgit.ttf" via "/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-blacklist.cnf".
luaotfload | db : Blacklisted file "spltfgrg.ttf" via "/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-blacklist.cnf".
luaotfload | db : Blacklisting 8 files and directories.
luaotfload | db : Whitelisting 0 files.
luaotfload | db : Scanning TEXMF for fonts...
luaotfload | db : Initiating scan of 519 directories.
luaotfload | db : Collected 2396 files.
luaotfload | db : Scanning system fonts...
luaotfload | db : Searching in static system directories...
```

At this point it stops -- forever. I have left it running for as long as a few hours, but nothing happens -- no errors, no clues, no additional lines of output that might indicate where the problem lies. I'm not certain if I have run `luaotfload-tool` since installing Mac OS 10.10 on this particular Mac. Other Macs with the same environment seem to have no issues at all. All of the output from `luaotfload-tool --diagnose=*` tells me that I can get a good night's sleep.

Puzzled, so insights would be gratefully accepted.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like something could be wrong with the filesystem. What happens if you run the `Disk Utility` app and click on `Verify Disk Permissions` followed by `Repair Disk Permissions` before re-running `luaotfload-tool`?

Comment: Good thought -- I should have thought of that myself. Alas, that did not seem to solve the problem...

Comment: Well, it was worth a try. :-) You may need to try re-downloading and -installing MacTeX. `luaotfload-tool` should definitely not take that long to run.

Comment: You're probably right. Though it seems odd to have to reinstall MacTeX because of the failure of one tiny, rather fragile piece of it. We shall see...

Comment: Add the option `--log=stdout`. Perhaps you can then see where it hangs.

Comment: I tried that on the chance that it might give more information, though, if I'm reading the manual for it correctly, that is the default. Same result: it hangs indefinitel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess I fixed the problem. From a post on StackExchange (from several, actually), I saw this:

```
luaotfload | db : Searching in static system directories...
luaotfload | db : Scanning directory ~/Library/Fonts
```

I was getting stuck at "Searching in static system directories..." -- there was no more output after that -- so I reasoned that the problem was in ~/Library/Fonts. I did not have much there so I cleaned it out and luaotfload-tool worked perfectly. What I did was a little stupid: I should have removed one item at a time in order to ascertain which file was causing the problem.

If only luaotfload-tool had output one more line, I could have been done with this a week ago.

Ah well.